# Exchanging Code for Access Token

Tags: beatsmusic

I am continually getting a 403 when trying to exchange the code for the access token.  I have double checked the URI and it seems to match the scheme prescribed.

Here is the URI I am using: 
https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/oauth2/token?client_secret=HIDDEN&client_id=HIDDEN&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1337%2Fcomplete&code=HIDDEN&grant_type=authorization_code

Comment: I have also tried with the redirect URI escaped and unescaped as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/oauth2/token?client_secret=HIDDEN&client_id=HIDDEN&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1337%2Fcomplete&code=HIDDEN&grant_type=authorization_code

This looks correct. You do need to send it as a post.

Comment: I am sending it as a POST.